# img not showing in html using php

Tags: php, html, image

Having a problem showing image in my code using php

I am using an image profile update, when I use an image tag the normal way using html it shows in the browser and when I view the page source it shows with a link as it should

```
 <img src="profile_images/profile/be2b496164.png"/> // underlined link
```

But when i echo it out using php

```
echo '<img scr="'. $user->data()->profile. '"/>';
```

The image stores in the proper file path correctly and it stores in the database correctly. But the image does not show in the browser. And when I view the page source it shows exactly as the normal html method but without the link

```
<img src="profile_images/profile/be2b496164.png"/> // no underlined link
```

I do not understand what the problem is... Any help is always appreciated

Comment: `echo '<img scr=` => `echo '<img src=` **IF** that is your actual code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- are you saying I should echo an echo? I am not quite grasping what you are saying.. Yes it is my code, I didnt get that either?

Comment: You made a typo, `scr` instead of `src` - New code `echo '<img src="'. $user->data()->profile. '"/>';`

Comment: I apologize I looked at it closer and realized what you were saying... Please forgive me and thank you

Comment: You're welcome. So, problem solved then? I can put in an answer to close it, or you can choose to delete your question. Just glad it got resolved.

Comment: You're quite welcome. It has been posted, *cheers*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per OP's request to close the question:

There is a typo in your code:

```
echo '<img scr="'. $user->data()->profile. '"/>';
           ^^^
```

it should read as `src` instead of `scr`

```
echo '<img src="'. $user->data()->profile. '"/>';
```